# How to selectively change a UITableviewCell appearance with static other cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have good reason to adopt static `UITableViewCell` design because after long effort I have come up with the table format I want. I have all my `tableView` rows designed in my storyboard.

Now, just for a single row - to put checkmark in that row - I am finding no way. I need to do it based on my program logic.

If I implement the datasource method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I will need to do something for all other cells, too. And while doing it, I will erase up all the formatting I did statically to other cells. If I return `nil` for all other cells, they won't show up.

I tried to single out this specific cell with this code, in my `UITableViewController`'s `viewdidLoad:`

```
NSIndexPath* NotifyRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:NotifyRow];

if (MYCONDITION_IS_TRUE)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

But above doesn't work because I always get `cell=nil`. Due to its built in mechanism, when it has table design in storyboard, it doesn't share it in `self.tableView` structure. I tried changing rows and section values in first statement, but all cells come out to be `nil`.

How do I single out this one cell that I want to modify, from static design?

Answer (score 0):

Soon after posting, I realized my mistake. I was calling cellForRowAtIndexPath too early to get the cell - even before the view was fully laid.

Just added one row on top of everything in my viewDidLoad, and it worked:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

So the whole will look like:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSIndexPath* NotifyRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:NotifyRow];

if (MYCONDITION_IS_TRUE)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```